# Error when Trying to run an sql command on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

```
%load_ext sql
%sql postgresql:/test:test@localhost:5432/tm351test
```

```
Error message : connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format example
```

Comment: `sql-server` tag refers to Microsoft SQL Server RDBMS. PostgresSQL is a different RDBMS. It would be helpful if you added some more details, like the fact you're using `ipython-sql`, which parts of the string you meant to be username, host, port, database, and also made sure the question is correctly formatted. As to the error, I think your first `/` should actually be `//` as per [SQLAlchemy database URL format](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls). `%sql 'postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/tm351test'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `/` should actually be `//` as per [SQLAlchemy database URL format](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls) which is

```text
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

So your connection string is that one typo away from being correct:

```ipython
%sql 'postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/tm351test'
```